# Suggestion for CSS solution to make a smaller preview div

Tags: jquery-ui, css, transform

[image]

As in image you can see I have a bigger div on left and smaller div on right. Smaller div is basically a preview div so whatever is added to bigger div on left should be re-sized and come in smaller div. Something similar to powerpoint
currently I am doing this

```
$('#slideContent0').css('-ms-transform', 'scale(0.5, 0.5)');
```

But this does not seems to be working, I mean initially it works well, but when I add something to slide the preview div kind of looks like this
[image]

the HTML for preview slide is something like

```
<div class="leftPanelContent" id="leftPanelContent">
    <div id="slidePreview0" class="slidePreview">
        <div id="slideContent0" class="slideContent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS I am using is

```
.slidePreview {
    width: 98% !important;
    height: 150px !important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #BCBCBC;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slideContent {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 130px !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: inherit;
}
```

Any suggestions

Comment: `overflow: hidden` to keep things from spilling out of the preview box?

Comment: I am really sorry if it sounds offensive, but did u read the question?

Comment: Apparently not. I assumed from the pic that you had made the divs as per the images and that your images where popping out of the smaller preview div.